# Send a response before timeout ends connection (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, api, timeout

I have an API in "nodejs" and i am trying to insert a timeout in some of my routes. I tried to do this using [res.setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_settimeout_msecs_callback), but the problem is: that way (as it should) closes the connection instantly. I would like to send a response before ending the connection, there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to just wait some time before doing a task? I would try leverage the setTimeout function -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

node 10+

```
// some code
// ...

// wait five seconds before moving foward
await new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve()
  },5000)
})

// move along...
```

Pre node 10

```
// some code
// ...

// wait five seconds before moving foward
setTimeout(() => {
  // move along in your code in this callback block
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

A timeout is a timeout. A misbehavior. It's not supposed to happen. It will send a 504 answer back to the user. Maybe you should try to configure your upfront http server (such as your nginx) to have the same timeout, if it's sending back a 500 to the end user instead of a 504.